# Why bot can ONLY subtract coins?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

When i use !flip  bot can subtract bet if random number less 60, but it does't work if random number more or equal 60. When winning the bot doesn't add coins to the user, but NUMBERS.
Example: user has 5000 coins, then he !flip 2000, random number drops out 80 (more 60) then balance of user becomes not 7000, its becomes 50002000
Help pls

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
let coins = require("../coins.json");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

  let bal = coins[message.author.id].coins;

  if (bal < args[0]) return message.channel.send(`${message.author}, not enough coins!`)

  if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send(`${message.author}, Write bet!`)

  if (random >= 60) {

  let win = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setDescription(`${message.author}`)
  .addField(`Victory!`, `Number: ${random}`)
  .setColor("YELLOW")
  message.channel.send(win)

    coins[message.author.id] = {
      coins: coins[message.author.id].coins + args[0]
    }
  };

  if (random < 60) {

    let lose = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(`${message.author}`)
    .addField(`Lose`, `Number: ${random}`)
    .setColor("RED")
    message.channel.send(lose)

    coins[message.author.id] = {
      coins: coins[message.author.id].coins - args[0]
    }
  }
 };

module.exports.help = {
  name: "flip"
}
```

Comment: I think it's because the 2 things you're adding up are both strings.

Comment: yeaa, but it should looks? :)) waiting for someone write...

Comment: Well I mean that would be spoon feeding, really

Comment: @Te1m0z what error are you getting?

Comment: @Syntle, no errors, just incorrect adding coins to the user's balance, must be 1000+500 = 1500... And i have 1000 + 500 = 1000500

Comment: i cant fix this((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not adding at all, you are combining strings together.

You need to either store the coins and balances as numbers or you can just convert the existing values using `parseInt()`

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
let coins = require("../coins.json");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

  let bal = parseInt(coins[message.author.id].coins); // Convert user's balance to number type

  if (bal < parseInt(args[0])) return message.channel.send(`${message.author}, not enough coins!`)

  if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send(`${message.author}, Write bet!`)

  if (random >= 60) {

  let win = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setDescription(`${message.author}`)
  .addField(`Victory!`, `Number: ${random}`)
  .setColor("YELLOW")
  message.channel.send(win)

    coins[message.author.id] = {
      coins: parseInt(coins[message.author.id].coins) + parseInt(args[0])
    }
  };

  if (random < 60) {

    let lose = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(`${message.author}`)
    .addField(`Lose`, `Number: ${random}`)
    .setColor("RED")
    message.channel.send(lose)

    coins[message.author.id] = {
      coins: parseInt(coins[message.author.id].coins) - parseInt(args[0])
    }
  }
 };

module.exports.help = {
  name: "flip"
}
```